# Prevent Android Ionic App from Reloading on Resume

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, ionic-framework, bluetooth

I have an ionic app running on android that reloads everytime I put the app into the background and resume it?
The reload is causing issues with some bluetooth devices I'm interacting with.

I know I can listen for the resume here, but not quite sure what I need to put in there to prevent the reload.

```
$ionicPlatform.on('resume', function(){
...
})
```

What can I do to prevent app reload on resume?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks that you need a [Cordova plugin to prevent the app from going to sleep while in background](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode).

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts. Actually tried that, but didn't do what I needed. It's not so much that I need to prevent the app from pausing its that I need to prevent the app from refreshing on resume.

Comment: @Justin tell me please is the app starting with the splash screen and everything every time you put it in the background? Also, Is the app going in the background by pressing the home button?

Comment: The splash screen doesn't show again, but the scripts are getting refreshed.  And there is flash as if a reload is happening. The app is going into the background when I press the home button.

Comment: @Justin hmm maybe you should post some code. From what i know reload could happen if you are having an open connection that is getting lost when u put the app on the background or if you have the app in the background for a period of time, Android can kill it to free up resources.